# View vs Change methods of Smart Contracts

Tags: smartcontracts, nearprotocol

I have been reading the docs and evaluating examples when I discovered two types of functions in smart contracts: view and change methods.

> // View methods are read only. They don't modify the state, but usually return some value.
>
> // Change methods can modify the state. But you don't receive the returned value when called.

from https://docs.nearprotocol.com/hackathon/hackathon-startup-guide-10-min

How strict are those requirements? What is going to happen if those assumptions are not held (e.g. state gets modified inside a view method or no modifications are done inside a change method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As berryguy said, `near view` will fail if the function tries to change the state. However, I as suggested here https://github.com/nearprotocol/NEPs/pull/3#discussion_r306526647 the restriction is artificial and should be dropped. We should allow users to run any function as `near view` and treat it as a dry run, because it has multiple nice usages:

- A user can dry run a function to estimate how much gas it consumes;
- A user can dry run to see how function will behave with the current
  state of the contract.

Answer (score 2):

If you try to change state in a view function, the view call will fail. The difference is really only manifested when you call the function. View functions should be called through `near view` whereas change functions should be called through `near call`.